# Import don't run in python

Tags: python-3.x, import

I am developing a Django project and I am trying to run a test file but an error in the import occurre.
My folder hierarchy to be like the image:

[image]

[image]

see the image of function process_data inside of core.py

[image]

I am in the test directory trying to run my test file.

My import to be like the code:

```
from coordenadas.core import process_data
```

but, when I run my code an error is showed:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tests_class_moviment.py", line 1, in <module>
    from coordenadas.core import process_data
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'coordenadas'
```

I am tryed use relative import

```
from .coordenadas.core import process_data
from .core import process_data
from ..coordenadas.core import process_data
from ..core import process_data
```

but the only way that no error is showed in pycharm is the

```
from coordenadas.core import process_data
```

Some idea how can I solve it?

Answer (score 0):

On a partially unrelated note, absolute imports are definitely recommended over relative imports. PEP8:

> Relative imports for intra-package imports are highly discouraged. Always use the absolute package path for all imports. Even now that PEP 328 [7] is fully implemented in Python 2.5, its style of explicit relative imports is actively discouraged; absolute imports are more portable and usually more readable.

As for the module error itself, adding an `__init__.py` file to the "coordenadas" directory will turn it into a module, which is exactly what you need.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

In my folder coordenadas exists the file __init__.py.

Comment: @EricGomes I see. Please include the whole folder structure so I can help you better. I also don't see the `core` file you specified in the original question.

Comment: Sorry @Dolev P , I updated my post with new image.

Comment: I can still not see the `core` directory. Please post your folder structure as text if you can.